# Pivoting from dataframe to unique variable and multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to pivot this dataframe:

```
       Ticket          Final_Phase               Datestamp
1    C1550135   IMAC F1 Aprobacion 2019-04-01 12:00:58.000
2    C1550135 IMAC F1 Alistamiento 2019-09-18 17:25:56.000
3    C1550135 IMAC F1 Programacion 2019-09-18 17:54:02.000
4    C1550135    IMAC F1 Ejecucion 2019-09-18 17:54:41.000
5    C1550135   IMAC F1 Validacion 2019-09-18 18:15:34.000
6    C1550135       IMAC F1 Cierre 2019-09-20 16:18:26.000
```

into this:

```
    Ticket      IMAC.F1.Aprobacion    IMAC.F1.Alistamiento    IMAC.F1.Programacion       IMAC.F1.Ejecucion      IMAC.F1.Validacion
1 C1550135 2019-04-01 12:00:58.000 2019-04-01 12:00:58.000 2019-04-01 12:00:58.000 2019-04-01 12:00:58.000 2019-04-01 12:00:58.000
2 C1564390 2019-04-01 12:00:58.000 2019-04-01 12:00:58.000 2019-04-01 12:00:58.000 2019-04-01 12:00:58.000 2019-04-01 12:00:58.000
```

so I tried:

```
Dset_Pivot <- Dset %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(Ticket) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Final_Phase", values_from = "Datestamp") %>%
  select(-row)
```

and got this output:

```
    Ticket   IMAC F1 Aprobaci~ IMAC F1 Alistami~  IMAC F1 Programa~  IMAC F1 Ejecucio~  IMAC F1 Validaci~ 
1 C1550135 2019-04-01 12:00:~ NA                 NA                 NA                 NA                   
2 C1550135 NA                 2019-09-18 17:25:~ NA                 NA                 NA                   
3 C1550135 NA                 NA                 2019-09-18 17:54:~ NA                 NA                   
4 C1550135 NA                 NA                 NA                 NA                 NA                   
5 C1550135 NA                 NA                 NA                 NA                 NA                   
6 C1550135 NA                 NA                 NA                 NA                 2019-09-20 16:18:~
```

Which works fine but I can't group df into unique Ticket values and non-NA values for every column.

I would like to know if there's an easier way to group and pivot the dataframe directly to the desired output or if I'm missing an extra step (in case this is the optimal way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the sequence column created.  It is created as the `row_number()` without any grouping i.e. if there are 1 million rows, the sequence would be 1- 1e6 and when we have a column sequence with that index, it is certain that the `pivot_wider` also have the same number of rows.  Instead, we need a `group_by` sequence

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Dset %>% 
   group_by(Ticket, Final_Phase) %>%
   mutate(row = row_number())  %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = "Final_Phase", values_from = "Datestamp") %>%
   select(-row)
# A tibble: 1 x 7
#  Ticket  `IMAC F1 Aprobaci… `IMAC F1 Alistami… `IMAC F1 Programa… `IMAC F1 Ejecuci… `IMAC F1 Validac… `IMAC F1 Cierre` 
#  <chr>   <chr>              <chr>              <chr>              <chr>             <chr>             <chr>            
#1 C15501… 2019-04-01 12:00:… 2019-09-18 17:25:… 2019-09-18 17:54:… 2019-09-18 17:54… 2019-09-18 18:15… 2019-09-20 16:1
```

Also, as @Dave2e mentioned in the comments, based on the example, the 'Final_Phase' values are `unique` for each 'Ticket'.  In that case, the creation of sequence and then removal is not needed i.e.

```
Dset %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = "Final_Phase", values_from = "Datestamp")
```

#### data

```
Dset <- structure(list(Ticket = c("C1550135", "C1550135", "C1550135", 
"C1550135", "C1550135", "C1550135"), Final_Phase = c("IMAC F1 Aprobacion", 
"IMAC F1 Alistamiento", "IMAC F1 Programacion", "IMAC F1 Ejecucion", 
"IMAC F1 Validacion", "IMAC F1 Cierre"), Datestamp = c("2019-04-01 12:00:58.000", 
"2019-09-18 17:25:56.000", "2019-09-18 17:54:02.000", "2019-09-18 17:54:41.000", 
"2019-09-18 18:15:34.000", "2019-09-20 16:18:26.000")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: There is no reason to mutate the row id and then remove it.  This will  `Dset %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Final_Phase", values_from = "Datestamp") `

Comment: @Dave2e yes, based on this example, but in a general case, we don't know whether the  'Final_Phase' have dupe values

Comment: The questions is whether there are duplicates of both Ticket **and** Final_Phase combinations.

Comment: @Dave2e I would wait for the OP to respond

Comment: Works perfectly on a 100K+ row  ```df``` and you were right bout the ```group_by``` sequence, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know you are using `dplyr`, but this would be a very simple thing to do with `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Dset)
Dset_Pivot <- dcast(Dset, Ticket ~ Final_Phase, value.var="Datestamp")
```

EDIT:

For the duplicates, one option would be to generate an ID for the duplicated entries:

```
DT[, ID := 1:.N, keyby=list(Ticket, Final_Phase)]
```

Then try

```
Dset_Pivot <- dcast(Dset, Ticket + ID ~ Final_Phase, value.var="Datestamp")
```

Comment: I get this ```Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length ``` so the dataframe returns without the original datestamp values

Comment: That means that Ticket does not uniquely identify observations in Final_Phase, i.e., you have multiple Final_Phase for some Ticket